# Bcrypt password verifying

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, bcrypt

I'm trying to decrypt the password on the login method, but it allows to login with any password I type in, not sure why, maybe someone could help me out?
My login method in the db layer:

```
public string loginUser(string userName, string pass)
{
    string result = "";

    try
    {
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("SearchForKnowledge");
        var coll = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");

        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("userName", userName);
        var results = coll.Find(filter).ToList().First();
        if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(pass, results["password"].ToString()))
        {
            result = results["userName"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = "";
    }
    return result;
}
```

My user controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(UsersLogin form)
{
    User user = new User();
    UserDB udb = new UserDB();

    if (!form.Username.IsEmpty())
    {
        udb.loginUser(form.Username, form.Password);
        Session["userName"] = form.Username;
        return RedirectToRoute("Home");
    }
    return RedirectToRoute("Login");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your controller

```
udb.loginUser(form.Username, form.Password);
Session["userName"] = form.Username;
return RedirectToRoute("Home");
```

You call `udb.loginUser(form.Username, form.Password);`, but you never check the return value of `udb.loginUser` method, so your code will always redirect to the home page no matter what the user name and password are.

Based on the code of `loginUser` method, it will return an empty string if the login fails, so change the above three lines of code to below

```
var loginResult = udb.loginUser(form.Username, form.Password);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginResult))
{
    Session["userName"] = form.Username;
    return RedirectToRoute("Home");
}
```